# Converting template parameter safely to long

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a legacy MFC application that seems to be using in several wrong ways the conversion to HashKey...

There is the following template method:

```
template<class ARG_KEY>
AFX_INLINE UINT AFXAPI HashKey(ARG_KEY key)
{
    // (algorithm copied from STL hash in xfunctional)
    ldiv_t HashVal = ldiv((long)(ARG_KEY)key, 127773);
    HashVal.rem = 16807 * HashVal.rem - 2836 * HashVal.quot;
    if (HashVal.rem < 0)
        HashVal.rem += 2147483647;
    return ((UINT)HashVal.rem);
}
```

It gives me an error on the line:

```
ldiv_t HashVal = ldiv((long)(ARG_KEY)key, 127773);
```

One output says:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'GUID' to 'long'
```

If static cast the error is `cannot convert from 'HMENU' to 'long'` which is also a problem.

Is there a way to cast whatever comes into `long`??

### Solution

Thanks to @Joachim Pileborg

After navigating the almost 1million lines of code it seems that the program is only using the first variable from the `GUID` structure.

Thus I overloaded the template according to what is expected:

```
template<>
AFX_INLINE UINT AFXAPI HashKey<GUID>(GUID key)
{
    return key.Data1>>4;
}
```

Comment: A non-primitive type (like a structure) can never be converted to a primitive type, unless you have an appropriate conversion operator defined for the complex type.

Comment: The `GUID` is an struct composed of several data types, maybe a clever casting and an extra specialization to the template will provide a more defined cast. Thanks @JoachimPileborg

Comment: You should probably use [specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), like is done with the [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) structure. Having a generic all-types hash-function might give working results for all types, but the results will not be optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the process necessary to create the specialization:

1. Investigate **ALL** the uses of `HashKey` for `GUID`
2. Check what is using or expecting

The conclusion was that the original version in MFC 6.0 used the first element of the `GUID` `structure` (with a very very nasty conversion). The first element of the `GUID` is a `long` type so the casting was all right.

Thus we create the following specialization **IN THE PROJECT** and not in the **MFC** libraries:

```
template<>
AFX_INLINE UINT AFXAPI HashKey<GUID>(GUID key)
{
    return key.Data1>>4;
}
```

Which is how the `HashKey` is being used in the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is risky but if you must, you can try:

```
long key1 = *(long*)(&key);
```

Comment: And that will most likely yield different results for two different structures that are otherwise equal.